# Why do you have to initialize a constant that is declared an optional?

Tags: swift

Forgive this basic question.

I declare a constant to be an Optional String, then I go to unwrap it Using if let....

I'm getting the following error:

> Constant 'favoriteSong' used before being initialized

If I don't assign a value to an optional why isn't its value nil and the if let catch it?

```
let favoriteSong: String?
if let favoriteSong = favoriteSong {
    print("My favorite song is \(favoriteSong)")
} else {
    print("I don't have a favorite song")
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can `if let` with the same variable name, could be wrong.

Comment: You have to assign `nil` if you want it to start out `nil`. That's the way Swift works in this respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I don't assign a value to an optional why isn't its value nil and the if let catch it?

It would be, if you initialized it as `nil`, either like this:

```
let favoriteSong: String? = nil
```

Or like this:

```
let favoriteSong: String?
favoriteSong = nil
```

But you didn't do either. Thus, because you might still have done the second one, the compiler gives an error when you try to use the uninitialized variable.

Think about it this way: if

```
 let favoriteSong: String?
```

...automatically meant

```
 let favoriteSong: String? = nil
```

...then it would be *impossible* to say this:

```
let favoriteSong: String?
favoriteSong = "Rock Around the Clock"
```

...because this is a *constant* — it cannot be changed. But we need to be able to say that! It's legal syntax. Therefore that is *not* what

```
 let favoriteSong: String?
```

...means. Do you see?

The rule for `var` is different, because it's changeable. Because of that, you get automatic default initialization to `nil` and can change it later.

But for `let`, you only get one shot at initialization, so you don't get the automatic default which would prevent you from doing your own initialization in the next line; you have to initialize explicitly.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now.  Thanks!